# Better way to execute ruby file using Python and How to get ruby console output when ruby file is run from python?

Tags: python, ruby

I am building a standalone using python.
This standaloone should execute a ruby file.

I have read this article - http://www.decalage.info/python/ruby_bridge
I have used os.system() which works well.
But I have an issue here.
If a ruby file has some error, file simply terminates without error.
Can you please let me know how to GET ruby  console output so that I can display the same in my standalone.

Answer (score 5):

you can use subprocess module

```
cmd="ruby myrubyscript.rb"                                                                          
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)                              
output, errors = p.communicate()
```

then use the `output` variable

Just a note, your Python program will be dependent on whether you have Ruby installed or not. If possible, try to do everything in Python.

Comment: Hi user131527,Thanks for the reply. But there seems to be  a problem.Output is not getting printed. For e.g. we take a ruby file  which has print "Hello world". now i use the code above and print Output. Output is not displayed. Same thing for errors - I mean consider ruby file with syntax error and try to print errors.

Comment: make sure import subprocess module. make sure your Ruby script actually prints out something.

Comment: i had imported subprocess module and ruby file is working. If i print output -> Blank is displayed and if i print errors -> None is Displayed

Comment: It Worked.. I just need to add stdout and stderr as PIPE.